# How do I publish an alteration to a replicated stored procedure (SQL 2000)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2000, replication

We have several stored procedures marked as articles for replication in our SQL2000 database.  If we update any of them via ALTER PROCEDURE, the changes are applied to the master, but never published to subscribers.  Am I missing a setting, or does SQL require a complete reinitialization/snapshot to move the changes out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two ways to update the stored procedure on master and subscribers

- Drop the replication article on the stored procedure, and recreate it
- Use the sp_addscriptexec stored procedure to replicate then execute a script containing the alter procedure command on the master and all subscribers

Source: http://www.replicationanswers.com/General.asp

Comment: Thanks, to be clear, it advises to drop the replication article for the procedure, not the procedure itself (attempting a drop on a replicated procedure will fail)